# Set of all functions and showing same cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, cardinals

The question is to show that $ \mathcal{P}(A)$~$ \mathcal{P}(B) $ and $\mathcal{F}(A,C)$~$\mathcal{F}(B,D)$ where A,B,C, and D are sets, $A$~$B$, $C$~$D$, and $\mathcal{F}(A,C)$ and $\mathcal{F}(B,D)$ are the sets of all functions for their respective sets.

I don't exactly know how to *prove* the two power sets are equal in cardinality when the sets themselves are equal in cardinality. It seems intuitive, but I don't know how to really explain it.

The set of all functions question, I don't even know really how to begin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Equal cardinality means there is a bijection.  Take bijections between A and B, and between C and D, and use those to construct bijections of the power sets and the function sets.

Comment: What do you mean by ZF and ZFC? I need to go back and read in my textbook about the axiom of choice. I remember we covered it, but I haven't really used it so I am a little forgetful.

Comment: Actually, I goofed.  Since you only have to make two choices (finitely many), you don't need the Axiom of Choice.

Comment: ZF and ZFC are "Zermelo-Frankel" and "Zermelo-Frankel with Choice", if you're still interested.  But not particularly relevant to the question you asked.

Comment: How do you construct the bijections, though?

Comment: I didn't mean to post that, but I just don't understand because I can't just arbitrarily construct them.

Comment: Are you familiar with the _image_ of a set under a function? (e.g., often you'll see $f''(A)$ defined as $f''(A)=\{f(a): a\in A\}$ )

Comment: Damn it. I am not used to it posting every time I hit enter

So can I say something like A and B are bijective.. and because F(B,D) is the set of all functions B-->D then it means that F(A,D)?

Comment: Okay, yeah, I am familiar with the image.

Comment: The bijection from $P(A)$ to $P(B)$is not arbitrary....you build it from a bijection $f$ from $A$ to $B$ that is arbitrary, but that you are allowed to select because of the magic words "$A$ and $B$ have the same cardinality".

Comment: So would it be correct to say then something like (I don't mean formally):

Since f:A->B is bijective, then P(A)->P(B) is bijective therefore P(A)~P(B)?

Comment: Not exactly.  You say something like: Let $g$ be the function that takes the subset $C\subseteq A$ to $\{f(c):c\in C\}\subseteq B$ and then validate that this is 1-1 and onto from $P(A)$ to $P(B)$.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand that. Any advice on the set of all functions part?

Comment: Do the same thing, essentially.  Sometimes it helps to think of bijections as providing the translation table for two sets of names for the elements in the same underlying set.  So imagine A and B are the same set, but every element has a first name and a middle name (and no names are repeated), and A is the first names and B is the middle names.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help!

Comment: @Tyler .Let $f:A\to B$ be a bijection . Define $f^*:P(A)\to P(B)$ by $f^*(a)=f''(a)$ for each $a\subset A.$ And let $g:C\to D$ be a bijection . For each function $\psi:A\to C$ define $h(\psi): B\to D$ by $(h(\psi)(f(x))=g(\psi (x)$ for each $x\in A,$ Or,  what is the same thing, for each $y\in B$ let  $(h(\psi))(y)=g(\psi (f^{-1}(y))$..... To get from $y\in B$ to $(h(\psi))(y)$ travel  from $B$ to a point in  $A$ via $f^{-1},$ then travel to a point in $C$ via $\psi,$ then travel via $g$ to the point $(h(\psi))(y)$  in $D.$